# Is it cheating to stratified split the whole dataset based on a previous test set result?

Tags: machine-learning, image-segmentation

I trained a model using a small mri dataset(57 patients). The model's performance was so low(Train set 0.7, Val set 0.7, Test set 0.45).

I found the model segments tumor in upper part of brain well, couldn't segment tumor which is in middle part of brain(information from validation + test).

So i stratified split the whole dataset with a position stratum(upper, not upper), the model performance was improved. I test this 3 times with different random states for split, average test accuracy increased a little.

In this case, is it cheating to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the first scores `train set 0.7, val set 0.7, test set 0.45` shows that your model suffers from overfitting.

Because of you have a really small dataset you can try `one leave out cross-validation` technique to train your model.

Another thing that you need to be careful is about the distribution of your target. From your question, I understand that your problem is binary but what is the 0/1 ratio?

I can edit my answer based on this.

```
Ex: 57 samples, and the distribution of your all dataset is like below.

20 examples from the upper part of the brain.
25 examples from the middle part of the brain.
12 examples from the lower part of the brain.

In this case, you can split the train/test (80:20) like below to ensure the same train/test distribution.

Train set: Total Example: 46 (57 * 80/100)
46 example contains: 
1. 20 * 80/100 = 16 upper part sample
2. 25 * 80/100 = 20 middle part sample
3. 12 * 80/100 = 10 lower part sample

Testset: Total Example: 11 (57 * 20/100)
1. 20 * 20/100 = 4 upper part sample
2. 25 * 20/100 = 5 middle part sample
3. 12 * 20/100 = 2 lower part sample
```

Comment: The objective  is to segment tumor in mri images.

Comment: what is the target class distribution?

Comment: There is no target. All images have tumors. It's an image-segmentation problem.

Comment: ahh, i see. So one leave out cv should work for you because you have very little dataset. You can train with 56 images and test the other one. You need to do it 57 times. Then take the average score of your predictions.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to do that. Btw, was what i did considered cheating?

Comment: Yes it seems like cheating. Because you know that you can predict well the upper part and not good for other parts, you use this knowledge and split your dataset based on this information. So in the real life, if the examples come too much from middle part of brain your model real life accuracy will be much lower that your training and validation accuracy. So you need to split it based the number of example. I added a little example on my answer.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Btw, what i did was what you wrote in your answer. So, If i stratified split the whole set, is it not considered cheating, isn't it?

Comment: If you did it like what I wrote, there is no cheating. You divide your train and test set based on your current distribution. The main important thing is you shouldn't use any posterior information for splitting. For example, you know that you can work well on upper part examples so if you put these example too much in your test set, probably your model will give high accuracy. So don't do this. Use only the current distribution information when you are splitting the data